# How can I undelete my question that I deleted?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-undelete

I deleted my question, but I really shouldn't have. Is it permanent? Can I undelete it somehow?

I thought I had missed something really fundamental, making my question very silly and embarrassing. But, I was mistaken. It was a good question. And, there were some thoughtful comments that are worth retrieving. Plus, I really don't want to recreate the post.

I looked in my activity and questions, but I couldn't find any sign of the deleted question.

Comment: Questions are never embarrassing, they are at their worst asked too soon.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scroll down to the bottom of [your questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2391771/kaleb-coberly?tab=questions) ("Questions" tab) in your profile page. See that really tiny text there at the bottom that says "recently deleted questions"? Click it. You can then see [your recently deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/2391771), which you can then open and undelete, if you like.

Incidentally, the same feature exists in a similar place for "recently deleted answers".

As the name suggests, this only works for *recently* deleted questions. "Recently", in this case, is defined to be within the past 60 days. If you need access to a question that is older than that, you have little choice but to ask a diamond moderator to help you. We can see all of a user's deleted posts, regardless of age. Diamond moderators can be contacted via flags, on Meta, or sometimes lurking in a chat room that you hang out in.

Finally, it's worth noting that there are some cases in which you would *not* be able to undelete a recently-deleted post. Specifically, if the post were deleted by a diamond moderator. Then, the system assumes that we had a good reason for deleting it, and it doesn't allow you to override that decision. At that point, you also have to involve a diamond moderator. You can raise a flag on such posts, asking them to be undeleted, but you'd better have a good reason—like, you heavily edited it to address the issues with it. But that doesn't apply in your case; you can always undelete something that you, yourself, deleted.